# Microsoft.DNX.Props not found

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, visual-studio-2015

When i use teamcity to build my VS 2015 project it is getting following error

C:\BuildAgent\work\d7ea2313e2af8fcf\src\Test2015\Test2015.xproj(7, 3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

How can i solve this problem.
Teamcity version - 9.1.3

Comment: Have you confirmed that the file exists on the build agent at that path?

Comment: We have installed VS 2015 on the server and now the above issue is fixed and the above file is now exist,  but now it is complaining "The Dnx Runtime package needs to be installed "

Comment: Can we just install "the tools" rather than the whole of VS 2015?

Comment: with vs 2013 it is not found too((((((( as well as dotnet.exe